# Regular Expressions vs XPath when parsing HTML text

Tags: html, regex, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I want to parse a HTML text and find special parts. For example a text in 3rd `div` of 1st `row` and 2nd `column` of a `table`. I have 2 options to parse: Regular Expressions and XPath. What is advantages and disadvantages of each one?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think XPath is the primary option for traversing XML-like documents. With RegExp, it will be up to you to handle the different forms of writing a tag (with multiple spaces, double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, in one line, in multi-lines, with inner data, without inner data, etc). With XPath, this is all transparent to you, and it has many features (like accessing a node by index, selecting by attribute values, selecting simblings, and MANY others).

See how powerfull it can be at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/.

**EDIT:** See also [How do HTML parses work if they're not using regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm)

Answer (score 10):

It somewhat depends on whether you have a complete HTML file of unknown but well-formed content versus having merely a snippet or an expanse of HTML of completely known content which may or may not be well-formed.

There is a difference between editing and parsing, you see.

It is one thing to be editing your own HTML file that you wrote yourself or are otherwise staring right in the face, and you issue the editor command

```
:100,200s!<br */>!!g
```

To remove the breaks from lines 200–300.

It is quite another to suck down whatever HTML happens to be at the other end of a URL and then try to make some sense out it, sight unseen.

The first calls for a regex solution — the very one shown above, in fact.  To go off writing some massively overengineered behemoth to do a fall parse to set up the entire parse tree just to do the simple edit shown above is quite simply wrong. It’s also its own punishment.

On the other hand, using patterns to parse out (as opposed to lex out) an entire HTML document that can contain all kinds of whacky things you aren’t planning for just cries out for leveraging someone else’s hard work intead of recreating the wheel for yourself, and badly at that.

However, there’s something else nobody likes to mention, and that’s that most people just aren’t competent at regexes. They don’t really understand them.  They don’t know how to test them or to craft them.  They don’t know how to make them readable and maintainable.

The truth of the matter is that the overwhelming majority of regex users cannot even manage as simple and basic a thing as matching an arbitrary HTML tag using a regex, even when things gotchas like alternate encodings and  CDATA sections and redefined entitities and `<script>` contents and archaic never-seen forms are all safely dispensed with.

It’s not because it’s hard to do; it isn’t, actually.  It’s just that the people trying to do it understand neither regexes nor HTML particularly well, *and* they don’t *know* they don’t know, and so they get themselves in way over their heads more quickly than they realize.  And then they have a complete disaster on their hands.

Plus it’s been done before, and correctly.  Might as well learn from someone else’s mistakes for a change, eh?  It would probably help to have a few canned regexes at your disposal to go at frequently manipulated things.  This is especially useful for editing.

But for a full parse, you really shouldn’t try to embed a full HTML grammar inside your pattern. Honest, you really shouldn’t. Speaking as someone has actually *can and has* done this, I unlike 99.9999% of the responders here the credibility of actual experience in this area when I advise against it. Sure, I can do it, but I almost never want to, and I certainly don’t want you to try it at home unsupervised. I can’t be held responsible for any damage that might ensue. :)

Sure, this may sound like “Do as I say, not as I do,” but if your level of regex mastery were at a level that allowed you to contemplate such a thing, you would not be asking this question.  As I mentioned, almost no one who uses regexes can actually match an arbitrary HTML tag, simple as that is. Given that you need that sort of building block before writing your recursive descent grammar, and given that next to nobody can even manage that simple building block, well...

Given that sad state of affairs, it’s probably best to use regexes for simple edit jobs only, and leave their use for more complete solutions to real regex wizards, for they are subtle and quick to anger.  Meaning of course the regexes, not (just) the wizards.

But sure, keep some canned regexes handy for doing simple editing rather than full parsing.  That way you won’t be forced to redevise them each time from first principles. I do keep a few of these around, but then I also keep simple frameworks that allow me to edit a particular structural element of the HTML, like the plain text or the tag contents or the link references, etc, and those all use a full parser, letting me then surgically target just the parts I want in complete confidence I haven’t forgotten something.

More as a testament to what is possible than what is advisable, you can see some answers with more, um, “heroic” pattern matching, including recursion, 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181653/regex-matching-tag-names-only-in-html/7182478#7182478),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044946/regex-to-split-html-tags/4045840#4045840),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031112/regular-expression-matching/4034386#4034386),
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168670/regex-that-matches-xabc-but-not-x-alone/4169358#4169358), and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840988/the-recognizing-power-of-modern-regexes/4843579#4843579).

Understand that some of those were actually written for the express purpose of showing people why they should *not* use regexes, because some of them are really quite sophisticated, much moreso than you can expect in nonwizards.  That difficulty may chase you away, which is ok, because it was sort of meant to.

But don’t let that stop you from using `vi` on your HTML files, nor should it scare you away from using its search or substitute commands. Don’t let the perfect be the enemy of the good.  Sometimes good enough is exactly what you need, because the perfect would take more investment than it could ever be worth.

Understanding which out of several possible approaches will give you the most bang for your buck is something that takes time to learn, and no one can tell you the answer that works for you.  They don’t know your dataset, your requirements, your skillset, your priorities.  Therefore any categorical answer is automatically wrong. You have to evaluate these things for yourself.

Comment: Half a year after posting of this answer, but I simply had to say it: this is simply _the_best_ analysis of HTML, parsing and regular expressions in connection to each other, I've seen on SO! It's also the closest to my own view of the matters. It isn't as epicly upvoted as another “famous” answer, but it's meritoriously the better one by far.

Comment: @thebodzio Thank you. It’s true that [a certain answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491) has a few more votes, but this time around I  sought to persuade with prose instead of with mind-numbing code. And I *certainly* don’t try to persuade by senseless joking, as seems commonplace ’round these parts. Completely useless, that.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree about “senseless joking”

Answer (score 4):

XPath is less likely to break if the web developer does any minor changes. That would be my choice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the canonical Stackoverflow explanation for why you should not parse HTML with regex:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

In general, you cannot parse HTML with regex because regex is not made to parse HTML. Just use XPath.