# Regex to get specific info from tags in HTML

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a HTML page with markup code like this:

```
<a href="#!/series/3078/series-name">
  <span class="title">This is series # 1</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>

<a href="#!/series/3079/series-name-2">
  <span class="title">This is series # 2</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>

<a href="#!/series/3080/series-name-3">
  <span class="title">This is series # 3</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>
```

I need to get the number after "/series/" and the text of the inner span of class "title".

How can I do this with a regex on PHP?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @cha0site Bull — yours is not a constructive comment and should be deleted. Given the supplied input and desired output, this is a perfect use for regexes.

Comment: @tchrist I respectfully disagree. Regexes on HTML have basically have one use where they don't work at all, which is validating user inputted HTML to search for `<script>` tags and such (cf "samy is my hero"), and one use which they're extremely good at, which is getting lists and such out of HTML pages. But when you want to get information from the DOM, as in this case (something out of an `<a>` tag + text from a specific child `<span>`) then regexs are no longer applicable. I'd use [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do this, I don't know what PHP has for that.

Comment: @cha0site You can be respectful and still be wrong, which you are. There is no reason whatsoever not to use a text editor on HTML. People do it all the time.

Comment: For all we know the HTML could be slightly changing, have different format at place, those spaces could be tabs, or what not, so @cha0site has a valid point. Using regex is not a good practice in such cases (unless you really know what you are doing), and we should inform the OP of that if he's not aware.

Comment: @Qtax: *entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem*: There is no reason to imagine that the circumstances are other that those that the querent has done us the courtesy to specify. Furthermore, as you will see in my answer, I gave the requisite citations, in which the provisos and caveats are laid out in exquisite detail, not through some risibile karma-whoring joke. And as it so happens, I *do* know I’m doing.

Comment: @Qtax: True. But isn't it kind of embarrassing that Stackoverflow can only offer a dated and technically not overly correct joke page for explaining alternatives to newbies?

Comment: @mario Indeed, which is why I always flag such comments as the first one here as being off-topic and non-constructive, and give a full and complete answer.

Comment: @tchrist, the OP doesn't, which is who I was referring to (the people who ask such questions).

Comment: @tchrist I think the appropriate Latin here is *Quod licet Iovi, non licet bovi*. You can obviously handle parsing anything with regular expressions. You literally wrote the book on it. However, when someone asks "I'm trying to parse HTML with regexs, and can't figure it out", the proper answer **is** "OK, don't do that, use a parser instead", instead of adding another special case to the regex. Because HTML parsers are not quite but almost as common as regex libs, and they're just so very good at parsing HTML.

Comment: @Qtax It would be hypocritical of me to tell people not to use the perfectly sufficient approaches that I myself use daily, and it would be condescending and insulting in the extreme to tell them that they aren’t smart enough to use these techniques.  I am willing to teach them, but I am not willing to treat them like idiots and go all patronizing on them. Nobody likes being told ***Do as I say, not as I do.*** It’s insulting. If they can use a regex in a text editor, they can use the same regexes outside of a text editor.

Comment: @tchrist "If they can use a regex in a text editor, they can use the same regexes outside of a text editor" - No, this is wrong. That a solution is appropriate in one context doesn't make it correct in another. A text editor, where you're looking at some very specific garbage and want to transform it into the garbage you want, is one context. A PHP script, which sits on a webserver and just processes garbage without you ever manually massaging the input, is another context. A regex is fitting for the first case, and if you know something about the input you'll get, the second. But generally?

Comment: @cha0site Indeed, the provided input set looked *very* specific, and certainly no indication that it was not as it appeared was given. Why should we make something up that isn’t in the question? Why must all solutions to all problems always be able to work sight-unseen on all possible HTML inputs, legal or otherwise? That’s what I call senseless overengineering. Solve the immediate problem, then go home and eat supper. If the input is really what he says it is, then a regex approach is just fine — wouldn’t you agree?

Comment: @tchrist Yes, definitely. I too do it all the time. My tip-off point was the use of PHP, to be honest. I know exactly one person who actually uses PHP as a general purpose scripting language. People mostly use it as a backend on HTTP servers, and that's the sort of environment where regexs are not appropriate. I mean, come on, it's pretty obvious he's writing a TV guide scraper...

Answer (score 1):

### Easy as Pi

Here is a little Perl program that demonstrates how easy it is to use regexes on little bits of HTML of very regular and known composition.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$_ = do { local $/; <DATA> };    
while ( m!/series/(\d+)!g ) {
    print "Series $1: ";
    if ( m!<span class="title">(.*?)</span>!g ) {
        print $1;
    }
    print "\n";
}    
__END__
```

```
<a href="#!/series/3078/series-name">
  <span class="title">This is series # 1</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>

<a href="#!/series/3079/series-name-2">
  <span class="title">This is series # 2</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>

<a href="#!/series/3080/series-name-3">
  <span class="title">This is series # 3</span>
  <span class="info">bla bla bla</span>
</a>
```

When run, that program prints out:

```
Series 3078: This is series # 1
Series 3079: This is series # 2
Series 3080: This is series # 3
```

See how easy that is? Nothing to it.

The same patterns will work with PHP, because I’m not doing anything that only Perl and not PCRE does.

---

## On the other hand...

Isn’t too hard to construct input that will mess up this particular approach.  Then again, it’s also not hard to compensate for that, too, as I have shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4231482/471272) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4286326/471272), amongst other places.

People edit HTML using text editors all the time.  This is perfectly normal.  And when they do so, they use regular expressions. It’s not like one program is blessed and another is cursed when they are doing the same thing. There’s nothing wrong with wanting to do do the exact same operation as you would do in your text editor from within a different program that is not your text editor.

However, for all but the simplest things (like this problem here, which counts as very simple), there is a trade-off, and most people asking how to do it are not able to do so.  I have a longer discussion about this paradox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7198796/471272).

Comment: Yeah, it's not hard if you like writing your own "parsers" in regex. And have fun dealing with all the details of "not so valid HTML" parsing.

Comment: @Qtax As it happens, I do enjoy such. But the problem specification as provided is a ***very limited one,*** one whose regex solution is trivial and self-apparent — and perfectly sufficient. To go off writing some massively overengineered behemoth to do a full parse to set up the entire tree just to do the simple extraction I have shown above is extreme idiocy. The invention of HTML did not obsolete such long-standing tools as `grep` and `vi`, and to pretend otherwise does a disservice to all. Solve the problem at hand, and don’t overengineer, and you’ll get to have supper with your family.

Comment: @tchrist +1 merely for that comment. I don't use perl much but my love of regular expressions is as strong as that of a perl guru such as yourself (I'd use regexes to make my dinner if I could). Most who cry Tony the Pony (and I have done so myself before) suggest an XML parser as an alternative, which makes just as many assumptions — namely that it's valid XML. Invalid XML and inconsistent code blocks can be catered for in either solution, but that doesn't mean to say *a priori* that one solution is better than the other. So if the OP asks for regexes, why not give ’em a regex?

Comment: @cbuckley: Because, *a priori*, parsers are a better solution to the problem of parsing HTML than regexs. Your invalid XML comment is a complete *non-sequitur* - it may not be valid XML, but it's almost definitely parse-able HTML. You don't find completely broken HTML "in the wild", people have to get it to at least show in a browser (a parser!). It's wrong to think about HTML as text - it's not text, it has structure, and that structure has meaning, and that makes regexs less useful for matching them. But regexs have an awesome and easy syntax, and are easy to use, so we use them anyway...

Comment: @cha0site “It’s wrong to think about HTML as text” — pure rubbish! Of course it’s text. So are English sentences, which you will note also have structure. I know! Let’s forbid `vi` from editing such structured text as English or HTML on the grounds of ivory-tower moral correctnessitude. That’ll sure be popular. We’ll just rap their impudent fingers with a wooden ruler whenever they try to use `vi` on HTML, and tell them to instead go haring off to write a brand-new special-purpose overengineered parser each time. They’ll be so pleased with our moral high ground. Don’t you want supper?

Comment: @tchrist Who said anything about writing a parser? They're already written, and they're good at what they do. Why not use them? And regexs are absolutely *horrible* for English parsing if you care about the structure. What's the regex for "a verb followed by a definite plural noun"?

Comment: @cha0site The regex for a verb immediately followed by a plural noun is `\w+/VB\S* \s+ \w+/NNP?S` — using standard Penn Treebank tags. :) The definiteness question is harder, because Penn tags aren’t in general rich enough; *e.g.* demonstrative adjectives also make a noun definite. Yes, I’ve done this sort of work, and this is actually a place where I argue that you **must** have the full parse structure available, that regexes are too hard to do it right given arbitrary recursion. That doesn’t stop people from using regexes to `1,$s/foo/bar/g` on their letter to Mom, or their dinner menus.

Comment: @tchrist I realized that I'm severely outclassed when, after reading your first comment here, I looked at your profile page... However, I'm still unconvinced. In my opinion, if you're writing a program that's going to be handling HTML files, the more *practical* solution will be would be to use a parser, then getting to the bits you want with XPath or other XMLy things. However, I have no new points to bring to the table, and so by Internet Law I have lost. Thank you for an interesting discussion!

Comment: @cha0site My personal rule of thumb is that if it is HTML I haven’t seen before, meaning I can’t visually inspect it, I always use a parser. If I can look at it, then it depends on the complexity of the problem. For simple greppy things, I don’t see why to bother.

Answer (score 0):

Here: (***EDITED!***)

```
preg_match_all($links, '/\/series\/([\d]+)\/.*?<span class="title">(.*?)<\/span>/ism', $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Hope that helps. I would suggest looking into DOMDocument in PHP however. I think it would be a cleaner solution. Regex tends to be ugly and slow.

Answer (score 0):

Whether regexs are a right tool for this job or not depends on what the job actually is. If you have a big HTML page, or a set of them, and you want to extract information from them, then regexs might be an OK fit. However, if your inputs are not under your control, then regexs are simply not what you want.

Anyway, the proper way to do this with PHP is just to parse the html using [DOMDocument::loadHTML](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), and just use the `DOMDocument` you get from that to `getElementsByTagName` and iterate over that. Maybe even use XPath if you're feeling fancy. That would always be a more robust tool than regexs for parsing HTML, unless you've actually written an HTML parser in regexs.

Answer (score -1):

If your markup is much longer than the snippet you've posted, then regex isn't the way to go as it is very expensive computationally.

(You can't fully parse XML with regular expressions anyway).

What I suggest is that you parse the markup with an [XML parser](http://uk.php.net/xml) which will let you traverse the tree structure it represents. This will allow you to get at the data you need easily.

If the `href` attributes always look like `#!/series/XXXX/series-name-2` then you access the `XXXX` through simple string parsing.

Comment: Of course you *can* fully parse XML with regular expressions — perferably using several of them and auxiliarly logic to control them.

Comment: @tchrist. No, no you can't. XML is not a regular language. You might want to read up on Regular Language Theory.

Comment: Don’t teach your granny to suck eggs.  And read what I wrote much more carefully, because you misunderstood it altogether. You very moist certainly can and do use regexes to pull out tokens to lex your input, even if that input is XML. How in the world do you think these things are done? And beyond that, modern patterns **ARE NOT YOUR GRANDMOTHER’S NAMBY-PAMBY *regular* LANGUAGES!** Modern patterns are fully equivalent to a context-sensitive recursive-descent parser, including the patterns used in PHP. Go read the references I included in the bottom of my answer.