# Using Boost.Spirit to extract certain tags/attributes from HTML

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

So I've been learning a bit about Boost.Spirit to replace the use of regular expressions in a lot of my code. The main reason is pure speed. I've found Boost.Spirit to be up to 50 times faster than PCRE for some relatively simple tasks.

One thing that is a big bottleneck in one of my apps is taking some HTML, finding all "img" tags, and extracting the "src" attribute.

This is my current regex:

```
(?i:<img\s[^\>]*src\s*=\s*[""']([^<][^""']+)[^\>]*\s*/*>)
```

I've been playing around with it trying to get something to work in Spirit, but so far I've come up empty. Any tips on how to create a set of Spirit rules that will accomplish the same thing as this regex would be awesome.

Comment: ok, I did comparative benchmarks using (1) [Boost Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8503402/85371) (2) [Boost Xpressive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8506725/85371), and (3) [Boost Spirit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8506789/85371). I hope that helps :) Find full benchmark details in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/c16725584493b021ba5b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I redid my regex sample based on Boost Xpressive, using statically compiled regexes:

```
sehe@natty:/tmp$ time ./expressive < bench > /dev/null

real    0m2.146s
user    0m2.110s
sys 0m0.030s
```

**Interestingly**, there is no discernable speed difference when using the dynamic regular expression; however, on the whole the **Xpressive version performs better than the Boost Regex version (by roughly 10%)**

> *What is really nice, IMO, is that it was really almost matter of including the `xpressive.hpp` and changing a few namespaces around to change from Boost Regex to Xpressive. The API interface (as far as it was being used) is exactly the same.*

The relevant code is as follows: (full code at https://gist.github.com/c16725584493b021ba5b)

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    using namespace boost::xpressive;
#if DYNAMIC
    const sregex re = sregex::compile
         ("<img\\s+[^\\>]*?src\\s*=\\s*([\"'])(.*?)\\1");
#else
    const sregex re = "<img" >> +_s >> -*(~(set = '\\','>')) >> 
        "src" >> *_s >> '=' >> *_s
        >> (s1 = as_xpr('"') | '\'') >> (s2 = -*_) >> s1;
#endif

    std::string s;
    smatch what;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();

        do
        {
            if (!regex_search(f, l, what, re))
                break;

            handle_attr("img", "src", what[2]);
            f = what[0].second;
        } while (f!=s.end());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So I did my own benchmark tests with PCRE, Xpressive and Spirit. I didn't try Boost.Regex because I don't want to deal with the building of boost libraries in my project if I can avoid it. I used a 400k HTML page pilfered from Yahoo as reference data, and parsed it 1000 times with each. Spirit took 19.5 seconds, PCRE took 13.5 seconds, and Xpressive took 3.5 seconds! The Spirit solution only found 39 matches compared to 63 for each of the others.

Comment: A 4x speed increase was more than I expected to get. I never tried Xpressive before, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: BTW I tried it again using the dynamic version, and that took 5.3 seconds, so the static regex is significantly faster in this case.

Comment: @Gerald: great thanks for the feedback too. Did you use the Spirit grammar I posted or your own?

Comment: I used basically your same code for everything, I just modified them to push the values to a std::vector instead of printing them. I also loaded the data completely into memory first instead of reading line-by-line from a file. In Debug mode the Spirit grammar kept throwing Debug assertions. I ran into that same problem when I was trying to create my own grammar before, I think it was choking on the mass of Javascript that is embedded in the page.

Comment: The Spirit solution found only 39 matches, whereas PCRE and Xpressive found 63? Then it seems the Spirit solution is buggy and can not be included in this comparison as is.

Comment: @Frank do you have the input, so I can fix the problem(s)?

Comment: @Frank, oh sorry. I found out you referenced [the first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501935/using-boost-spirit-to-extract-certain-tags-attributes-from-html/8506725#comment10533824_8506725). Well, I can't vouch for his input set, I merely showed the ideas and benchmarked it on input that produced identical results. (Sadly, I don't think I'd have kept the input, but I might look around).

Answer (score 3):

And of course, the Boost Spirit variant couldn't be missed:

```
sehe@natty:/tmp$ time ./spirit < bench > /dev/null

real    0m3.895s
user    0m3.820s
sys 0m0.070s
```

To be honest the Spirit code is slightly more versatile than the other variations:

- it actually parses attributes a bit smarter, so it would be easy to handle a variety of attributes at the same time, perhaps depending on the containing element
- the Spirit parser would be easier to adapt to cross-line matching. This could be most easily achieved

  - using `spirit::istream_iterator<>` (which is unfortunately notoriously slow)
  - using a memory-mapped file with raw `const char*` as iterators; The latter approach works equally well for the other techniques

The code is as follows: (full code at https://gist.github.com/c16725584493b021ba5b)

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

void handle_attr(
        const std::string& elem, 
        const std::string& attr, 
        const std::string& value)
{
    if (elem == "img" && attr == "src")
        std::cout << "value : " << value << std::endl;
}

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
typedef qi::space_type Skipper;

struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, Skipper>
{
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(html)
    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        using phx::bind;

        attr = as_string [ +~char_("= \t\r\n/>") ] [ _a = _1 ]
                >> '=' >> (
                    as_string [ '"' >> lexeme [ *~char_('"') ] >> '"' ]
                  | as_string [ "'" >> lexeme [ *~char_("'") ] >> "'" ]
                  ) [ bind(handle_attr, _r1, _a, _1) ]
            ;

        elem = lit('<') 
            >> as_string [ lexeme [ ~char_("-/>") >> *(char_ - space - char_("/>")) ] ] [ _a = _1 ]
            >> *attr(_a);

        html = (-elem) % +("</" | (char_ - '<'));

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(html);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(elem);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(attr);
    }

    qi::rule<It, Skipper> html;
    qi::rule<It, Skipper, qi::locals<std::string> > elem;
    qi::rule<It, qi::unused_type(std::string), Skipper, qi::locals<std::string> > attr;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::string s;

    const static grammar html_;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        It f = s.begin(),
           l = s.end();

        if (!phrase_parse(f, l, html_, qi::space) || (f!=l))
            std::cerr << "unparsed: " << std::string(f,l) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Update**
>
> I did benchmarks.
>
> Full disclosure is here: https://gist.github.com/c16725584493b021ba5b
>
> It includes the full code used, the compilation flags and the body of test data (file `bench`) used.
>
> In short
>
> - Regular expressions are indeed faster and way simpler here
> - Do not underestimate the time I spent debugging the Spirit grammar to get it *correct*!
> - Care has been taken to eliminate 'accidental' differences (by e.g.
>
>   - keeping `handle_attribute` unchanged across the implementations, even though it makes sense mostly only for the Spirit implementation).
>   - using the same line-wise input style *and* string iterators for both
> - Right now, all three implementations result in the exact same output
> - Everything built/timed on g++ 4.6.1 (c++03 mode), -O3
>
> ---
>
> *Edit* in reply to the knee-jerk (and *correct*) response that you shouldn't be parsing HTML using Regexes:
>
> - You shouldn't be using regexen to parse non-trivial inputs (mainly, anything with a grammar. Of course Perl 5.10+ [*'regex grammars'*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253760/have-you-used-the-perl-5-10-backtracking-control-verbs-in-your-regexes-yet) are an exception, because they are not isolated regexes anymore
> - HTML basically cannot be parsed, it is non-standard tag soup. Strict (X)HTML, are a different matter
> - According to Xaade, if you haven't got enough time to produce a perfect implementation using a standards compliant HTML reader, you should
>
> > *"ask client if they want shit or not. If they want shit, you charge them more. Shit costs you more than them."* -- [Xaade](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2103282#2103282)
>
> <sup>That said there are scenarios in which I'd do precisely what I suggest here: use a regex. Mainly, if it is to do a one-off quick search or to get daily, rough statistics of known data etc. YMMV and you should make your own call.</sup>
>
> For timings and summaries, see:
>
> - Boost Regex answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8503402/85371)
> - Boost Xpressive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506725/85371)
> - Spirit answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506789/85371)

I heartily suggest using a regex here:

```
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const boost::regex re("<img\\s+[^\\>]*?src\\s*=\\s*([\"'])(.*?)\\1");

    std::string s;
    boost::smatch what;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, s))
    {
        It f = s.begin(), l = s.end();

        do
        {
            if (!boost::regex_search(f, l, what, re))
                break;

            handle_attr("img", "src", what[2]);
            f = what[0].second;
        } while (f!=s.end());
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Use it like:

```
./test < index.htm
```

I cannot see any reason why the spirit based approach should/could be any faster?

**Edit** PS. Iff you claim that static optimization would be the key, why not just convert it into a Boost Expressive, static, regular expression?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, or someone will serial downvote all your answers. You could possibly get banned if one of the admins is drunk.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all of this good stuff. I was thinking that static optimization might be key based on some other recent work. Using Spirit to parse HTTP headers was about 2x slower than PCRE in Debug mode, but close to 50x faster in release mode with compiler optimizations cranked up. Of course I understood that particular parsing was right up Spirit's alley, since it was straight-forward and linear without much skipping needed, so I wasn't expecting similar results in this case, was just hoping it would help a little.

Comment: I'll give your Xpressive code a whirl and see how it compares to my existing PCRE code. Thanks for all of your effort here. I'd give you more upvotes if I could ;)